# Spring WebFlux endpoint performance logger

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-aop, project-reactor

Do you know any good practices to log Spring WebFlux controller endpoint performance to keep reactive nature? Seems the following principle wouldn't work because it will block the IO as the ProceedingJoinPoint doesn't return Publisher<> , it returns just an object

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect
{

    //AOP expression for which methods shall be intercepted
    @Around("execution(* com.company.service..*(..)))")
    public Object profileAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();

        //Get intercepted method details
        String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = methodSignature.getName();

        final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

        //Measure method execution time
        stopWatch.start();
        Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        stopWatch.stop();

        //Log method execution time
        log.info("Execution time of " + className + "." + methodName + " :: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " ms");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do a check using `instanceof` and the cast it to a mono or flux. An object is not blocking, depending on what type of object decides if it is blocking or not.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Really? Will check that thank you.

Comment: but on the other hand you will not be able to time a function like you have done, because a Mono/Flux will return immediately (much like a future). If you want to time a function you need to get a start time, and place it into the reactive context, then later in the chain, get another time, retrieve the first time from the context and then calculate the elapsed time.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yep did something like that passing with context and it counts I thing right. In my opinion it not includes transaction opening, R2dbc connection releasing times, because for the execution I receive for example 1 second but postman displays 1.5 seconds.  Thank you!

Comment: @Toerktumlare posted the final code what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually as mentioned @Toerktumlare in the comments `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` returns the type of object whatever is you controller endpoint return type, so it is possible to keep reactive nature. Note `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` is optional here, that is for my back code to support parallelism. Posting the solution for this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect
{

    //AOP expression for which methods shall be intercepted
    @Around("execution(* com.company.service..*(..)))")
    public Object logEndpointPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();

        //Get intercepted method details
        String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = methodSignature.getName();

        final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

        //Measure method execution time
        stopWatch.start();
        Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

        if(result instanceof Mono){
            return ((Mono)result).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).flatMap(r -> {
                logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch);
                return Mono.just(r);
            });
        }
        else if(result instanceof Flux){
            return ((Flux<Object>)result).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).collectList().flatMapMany(r -> {
                logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch);
                return Flux.fromIterable(r);
            });
        }
        else{
            logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private void logExecutionTime(final String className, final String methodName, final StopWatch stopWatch){
        stopWatch.stop();
        //Log method execution time
        log.debug("[ " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " mls ] lasted execution of" + className + "." + methodName );
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer in order to close the question. Thank you.